# Type conversion, explicit constructors etc

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, constructor, type-conversion

I have `BigNum` class.
What exactly methods, constructors etc. I need to implement to have desired effect (like in comments)?

```
class BigNum {
    //...?
};

BigNum a = 1; // compiles
a = 42; // compiles
BigNum b = 1L; // compiles
BigNum c = 1U; // compiles
BigNum d = 1UL; // compiles
BigNum e = true; // doesn't compile
BigNum f = '1'; // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Is that a guessing game C++ beginners or will you provide what **you** did yet to get behind it? I mean - it's just take you a few minutes to add some ctors, a `main()` and look yourself what your compilers complains about or not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> BigNum a = 1; //compiles
> BigNum b = 1L; //compiles
> BigNum c = 1U; //compiles
> BigNum d = 1UL; //compiles
> BigNum e = true; //doesn't compile
> BigNum f = '1'; //doesn't compile
> ```

For these you need **non-explicit constructors** that will accept integral types except `bool` and `char`. You can write a full set of integral overloads like those of [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string). Note that you don't need overloads for types smaller than `int` because they can be promoted to either `int` or `unsigned int` without ambiguity. You can delegate all of these calls to the `long long` and `unsigned long long` versions and only implement those two.

```
// remember to define these
BigNum(unsigned long long x);
BigNum(long long x);
BigNum(unsigned long x);
BigNum(long x);
BigNum(unsigned int x);
BigNum(int x);
```

To disable `bool` and `char`, you can delete those constructors. Then there will be an error for those lines you want errors for. If you don't do this, they'll just get promoted to `int` so there won't be an error.

```
BigNum(bool x) = delete;
BigNum(char x) = delete;
// you might also want to delete these:
// BigNum(char16_t x) = delete;
// BigNum(char32_t x) = delete;
```

Another approach is to define one constructor **template** that accepts any integral type, then define additional deleted overloads for `bool` and `char` as before. This avoids having to write multiple implementations.

```
template <typename Integral, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<Integral>::value>>
BigNum(Integral i);
BigNum(bool b) = delete;
BigNum(char c) = delete;
```

> ```
> a = 42; //compiles
> ```

For this you need assignment operators. You probably just want to play the same game here.

```
// remember to define these
BigNum& operator=(unsigned long long x);
BigNum& operator=(long long x);
// you can delegate these to the above
BigNum& operator=(unsigned long x);
BigNum& operator=(long x);
BigNum& operator=(unsigned int x);
BigNum& operator=(int x);
BigNum& operator=(bool x) = delete;
BigNum& operator=(char x) = delete;
// BigNum& operator=(char16_t x) = delete;
// BigNum& operator=(char32_t x) = delete;
```

Comment: But `BigNum(char) = delete;` alongside non-template integral-type overload yells "ambiguity", while alongside a template, it does not. I don't get exactly why.

Comment: @LogicStuff It is ambiguous for what argument?

Comment: @LogicStuff The template provides an exact match, so it beats any match via integral conversion. And any integral type can be converted to `char`. Two overloads will create an ambiguity when both require an integral conversion.

Comment: Can't you rely on the implicit conversions you just defined for the assignment?

Comment: @curiousguy Thanks, I got it.

Comment: @Brian At first, I thought that for all, because my code lit up red, but it was only the lines that required a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Not so simple, actually, because `bool` and `char` will implicitly convert to other integral types. But I've made this:

```
class BigNum {
public:
    template <
        typename T,
        typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value &&
            !std::is_same<T, bool>::value && !std::is_same<T, char>::value>::type>
    BigNum(T) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a template and **std::static_assert**:

```
struct BigNum {

    template <typename Int> BigNum(Int val)
    {
        std::static_assert(std::is_integral<Int>::value,"must be integral");
        std::static_assert(!std::is_same<Int,bool>::value,"can not be bool");
        std::static_assert(!std::is_same<Int,char>::value,"can not be char");

        // ...
    }
};
```

You can do it analogously for the `operator=`.

Answer (score -1):

Given this

```
a = 42; //compiles
```

you also need an assignment operator.
Simple example:

```
BigNum& operator=(const int n)
{
    // relevant stuff here...
    return *this;
}
```